# Magento 2 : Display Related Products Block in Product View

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, related-products

I'm using magento 2.1.3 and I want to display related products under product_view. Product view is using 1 column template.

I've added successfully related products to some products. I've reindexed after adding related to products. I've cleaned cache after each change of code.

**In**

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

The related products block is placed in **referenceContainer name="content.aside"** which is not present in my product view as it is one column.

I've overridden this layout in

> /app/design/frontend/myCompany/myTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

and every change is working except related products block.

I tried to move it like this

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="content" after="product.info.main" />
```

I used several different destinations, even without using after/before, but related products block is not appearing anywhere.

I tried also to call it

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" type="related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I tried even using and not using `type="related"` in this last way of calling, but even with or without the 'type' the block is not appearing.

Does somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
```

Change you `XML` file path from

> > `/app/design/frontend/myCompany/myTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/catalog_product_view.xml`

To

> > `/app/design/frontend/myCompany/myTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

Comment: I tried it before, but I tried it again now and it is not working.

Comment: change path, look updated answer

Comment: Actually it is in layout folder, it was a typo when copying. I edit it in the question to avoid future misunderstandings. I'm sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Call this Function

```
$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related')
                    ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml")
                    ->setData('type', 'related')
                    ->toHtml();
```